# What's the difference between config fonts in /etc/fonts/conf.d and gnome-tweak-tool?

Tags: fonts

I can change the hinting and sub-pixel settings from `/etc/fonts/conf.d` or `gnome-tweak-tool`. What's the difference of those two methods?

It seems to me that `google-chrome` and `gnome-terminal` changes more obviously from /etc/fonts/.